# sending the value from javascript(client side) to express (server side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I create the HTML DOM in javascript that you see the below code. Now, I want send the value of input that I created in javascript to server side. My server that created with node.js and express framework. After sending the value to server side, I want to save this value in my json file. I know how to read and write json file, but my problem is sending this value. Here is my javascript code and express code. In javascript code I want send the inTask variable and in the server code I want to receive this value in `app.post`.

1.javascript code

```
let newTask = [];
function addInput() {
    document.getElementById("link").style.display = "none";
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.setAttribute("id", "inValue");
    document.getElementById("input").appendChild(input);
    var addBtn = document.createElement("button");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Add Task");
    addBtn.appendChild(text);
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", addTask);
    document.getElementById("input").appendChild(addBtn);
 }

 function addTask() {
     var inTask = document.getElementById("inValue").value;
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/login", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-
       urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(document.getElementById("inValue").value);
     }
```

2. server.js:

```js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }));

app.get("/" , function (req, resp, next) {
   resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/index.html");
}) ;

app.post("/login" , function (req, resp, next) {
  var jsonData = req.body.inValue;
  fs.writeFile("data.json", jsonData, function(err) {
  if(err) {
     return console.log(err);
    }
  });
  res.json(jsonData);
 });

 app.listen(3000);
 console.log("app running on port 3000");
```

Comment: what is the problem with the current code. Any errors you are seeing ?

Comment: send empty value and not recognize the value of input box

Comment: You can use `ajax` for that purpose.

Comment: I used this ajax code, again send empty value:

Comment: Please edit your question instead of discussing it in the comments. And please mark code as code for better readability.

Comment: Did you found any error in browser console ?

Comment: no I don't have any error.

Comment: Before `send()` use `alert(document.getElementById("inValue").value);` just to ensure that correct data here before send. let me know the status.

Comment: when I write alert before sending, the value is correctly showed but when sending they send empty value, I think I have problem about sending. Maybe My sending code have problem

Answer (score 0):

You expect a json-Data in your server file, but you don't send a json-Object.
Exchange `xhttp.send(document.getElementById("inValue").value);` with

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify( { inValue: document.getElementById("inValue").value });
```